# CS0019 Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, runtime-error, operators

I'm currently working coding a simple dice game and I have run into a error which has left me confused, Here is my code.

```
foreach (var die in Dice.rolls)
{
    Console.WriteLine(die.ToString());
}
if (player.score += score >= goal)
{
    playing = false;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} has won the game!", player.name);
    Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to end the game");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
else
{
    player.score += score;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the line:

```
if (player.score += score >= goal)
```

Is throwing up an error telling me I can't use it on int's and bool's but all the variables in the if statement are int's. furthermore a few lines down here:

```
player.score += score;
```

Is not giving me any errors.

Comment: You can't do both operations in the same line. Just add the score first, then do the comparison. What you are telling the compiler to do is to solve score >= goal and add it to player.score, thus the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be priority of operations? Try:

```
if ( (player.score += score) >= goal)
```

Although, it seems to me you should either:
a) break it up into two lines:

```
player.score += score;
if (player.score >= goal)
```

or b) change the line to:

```
if (player.score + score > goal)
```

As it stands, and maybe this is intentional, player.score will end up having the score added twice if it isn't >= goal, as it would get added as part of the if, and then as the body of the else.

Comment: Yeah it was the priority of operations, cheers pal

Comment: It is much clearer to break it up into two lines. Trying to write terse code where you increment and check a variable in one line is likely to be a source of bugs in the future.

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of operator precedence. The comparison operator >= has a higher precedence, so in essence you are trying to increment `player.score` by the outcome of the boolean comparison `score >= goal`.

You can use parentheses to fix this or simplify your expression, e.g.

```
player.score += score;
if (player.score >= goal)
```

You can look up more information here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx